# Using containers of abstract class to hold children classes

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, interface, virtual-inheritance

I want several classes to inherit from this interface:

```
class IPlayer {

public:
     virtual ~IPlayer() {}

     virtual void doSomething() = 0;

protected:
     std::string m_name;

};
```

Here is a class that needs to inherit from the above:

```
class Jack : public IPlayer {

public:
      Jack(std::string t_name)
      {
             m_name = t_name;
      }

      ~Jack() { }

      void doSomething()
      {
              /* do a bunch of stuff */
      }

};
```

Keep in mind we have other classes that inherit from `IPlayer` in the same fashion, for instance `Bob` and `Alice`.

Now let's say I wanted to create a container for `Jack`s, `Bob`s and `Alice`s that would allow me to regroup them in a same variable. In this state it is impossible for me, as IPlayer has no ctor therefore cannot serve as a template for objects such as vectors or lists. (At least that's my understanding)

Would it be better to have a class in-between `IPlayer` and `Jack` which would implement only the ctor and dtor and then leave the other methods pure virtual to be exploited by the children;

**OR**

Make `IPlayer` (and/or any future interface) inherit from the same class as above that implements only ctor and dtor just to make `IPlayer` ctorable for containers?

Comment: You would use a container of (possibly smart) pointers to `IPlayer`, as in `std::vector<IPlayer*>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IPlayer>>`. Class `IPlayer` does already have a constructor - a default one; the reason an instance of it can't be created is because it's abstract. Adding more constructors won't change this fact.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Right, that is a most valid option. Why/how does using a container of pointers bypasses this problem though ?

Comment: Bypasses what problem? I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: If not for the ctor, what in an abstract class's intrinsic features makes it unable to serve as instance for containers?

Comment: You cannot create an instance of an abstract class, period; whether as element of a container or otherwise. That's kind of the point of pure virtual functions. You cannot have `std::vector<IPlayer>` for the same reason you cannot write `IPlayer player;` or `IPlayer* player = new IPlayer;`

Comment: Right, it's much clearer now. All of this roots to my misunderstanding of what abstract classes can or cannot do. I get now that I can use pointers or references to abstract classes but can't create an object from an abstract class. Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no problem with these classes. `IPlayer` might be an abstract class but you never need to create an instance of this class. You can perfectly declare a vector of pointers to IPlayers as long as the elements of the vector all  point to non abstract sub-classes.

```
Jack* j = new Jack("jack");
std::vector<IPlayer*> v = {j};
```

This code is perfectly fine since no instance of IPlayer is created.

Comment: While this is correct it is important to realize that using naked pointers is not a good approach. Who is going to delete the Jack player?

Comment: @rm1948 I used naked pointers to simplify my code. Ofcourse the OP can use smart pointers but that's his choice since I can't know what smart pointer is optimal for his system. I'm just showing how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The IPlayer can have a constructor and actually has one provided by the compiler.

Here's one approach that keeps the list of players in a static member of IPlayer. But the list doesn't have to be in IPlayer.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// forward declaration
class IPlayer;

using Players = std::vector<PlayerPtr>;

class IPlayer {
public:
    virtual ~IPlayer() {
    }
    static void addPlayer(IPlayer& player) {
        mPlayers.push_back(std::make_unique<IPlayer>(player));
    }
private:
    static Players mPlayers;
};

Players IPlayer::mPlayers;

class Bob : public IPlayer {
};

void run() {
    Bob bob;
    IPlayer::addPlayer(bob);
}
```